# Obtener valor radio button en Yii2

Tags: php, mvc, yii2

tengo una pregunta y un problema que no he podido resolver, es lo siguiente,estoy tratando de guardar un valor sacado de un radio button , pero cuando realizo mi guardado, en la vista me dice que el valor no está definido, tengo esto en mi vista .

```
<div class="d-md-flex justify-content-center align-content-center flex-column text-center">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= Html::hiddenInput('id_user', Yii::$app->user->identity->id); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '1. 1$ USD de suscipción.', 'value' => 1, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '2. PPV = Paga por el diagnostico que necesites.', 'value' => 2, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '3. Membresía limitada: 10 examenes por patología. Tarifa mensual/anual', 'value' => 3, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '4. Plan VIP : sonsultas ilimitadas. Tarifa anual/mensual.', 'value' => 4, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'terminos_y_codiciones')->checkbox(['label' => 'Para poder continuar necesita aceptar los Terminos y condiciones', 'value' => 5, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Registrate', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

y esto en mi controlador

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    $id_usiario = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

    $valor = Yii::$app->request;
    $numero_plan = ArrayHelper::getValue($valor->post(),  'Afiliacion.plan');
    $plan = (int)$numero_plan;
    //con esto veo el string que necesito
    // echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST );

    //echo '<pre>'; var_dump($plan);
    
    $model = new Afiliacion();
    

    if (empty($model->user_id && $model->plan)) {
        $model->user_id = $id_usiario;
        $model->plan = $plan;
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_afiliacion]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Con los var_dumps puedo ver el valor del radio button tranquilamente pero al momento de quitarlos para que realice el guardado , en la bdd me guarda un 0 y en la vista me dice que está indefinido, de verdad que no se que pueda ser, les agradezco de antemano por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta línea estás asignado el valor

```
$model->plan = $plan;
```

Y en esa en el `if` lo estas borrando

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

Cambia el orden

Answer (score 1):

Esto queda igual:

```
<div class="d-md-flex justify-content-center align-content-center flex-column text-center">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= Html::hiddenInput('id_user', Yii::$app->user->identity->id); ?>
```

Yo cambiaría esto:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '1. 1$ USD de suscipción.', 'value' => 1, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '2. PPV = Paga por el diagnostico que necesites.', 'value' => 2, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '3. Membresía limitada: 10 examenes por patología. Tarifa mensual/anual', 'value' => 3, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plan')->radio(['label' => '4. Plan VIP : sonsultas ilimitadas. Tarifa anual/mensual.', 'value' => 4, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
```

Por lo siguiente:

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'plan', [
     ->radioList([
        1 => '1. 1$ USD de suscipción.', 
        2 => '2. PPV = Paga por el diagnostico que necesites.',
        3 => '3. Membresía limitada: 10 examenes por patología. Tarifa mensual/anual',
        4 => '4. Plan VIP : sonsultas ilimitadas. Tarifa anual/mensual.'
     ]);
?>
```

Esto queda igual:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'terminos_y_codiciones')->checkbox(['label' => 'Para poder continuar necesita aceptar los Terminos y condiciones', 'value' => 5, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Registrate', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Y en el controller lo siguiente:

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    
    $model = new Afiliacion();
     
    //Con este if ya estás cargando todo lo que viene de la vista y lo guarda 
   //en el modelo, no necesitas más validaciones ni cargar el valor con ->post() 
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_afiliacion]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```